# How to calculate the same position on different bitmaps?

Tags: android

I have 2 photos, one has a dimension of `300x300` and the other one is `1200x1200`. 
I drew one text to the position `A = (50, 40)` in the `300x300` image.

How can I calculate the same position A on the `1200x1200` image?

UPDATE 2:

IF dimension is not round (such as 523 x 412...) - x, y after multiply will be deflected

Comment: What's the relationship between the two images?

Comment: these are same image with different size

Comment: IF dimension is not round (such as 523 x 412...) -  x,y after multiply will be deflected

Comment: How can the position be greater than the original image? 523 > 300 and 412 > 300... `You can't fit a text at position 523,412 in a 300x300 image`.

Comment: @Der Golem: it's mean "image dimension not postion"

Comment: You should better use the **same proportions** (ratio) for both images. 300*300 has a ratio of **1**, and so has 1200x1200. While `523x412` has a ratio of **1.269###...** (or **0.787###**). It makes sense to use a same scaled picture. I.e.: `1046x824`.

Answer (score 2):

you may go with relative position calculation as follows.

```
AAx = (50/300)*1200; 

AAy = (50/300)*1200;
```

so your new position will be `AA = (200,200)`

Answer (score 2):

The scaling factor for both x and y is `1200/300 = 4`.
Then, simply multiply both x and y by `4` (your scaling factor).

```
int scaleFactor = 1200 / 300;
int newX = oldX * scaleFactor;
int newY = oldY * scaleFactor;
```

So, given that oldX = 50 and oldY = 40, the expectex values for newX and newY are 200 and 160, respectively.